# I'm looking for mountain image like this

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, stock-images

I'm looking for mountain and lowland image like this. I searched in google also in pixabay but i didn't find similay result.

Which keyword that i should use?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

On Shutterstock I was able to find some useful stuff with Mountain Topography and Mountain Rendering. If you scroll down and look at the Similar Lists you can then find more:

[image]

[image]

It kinda reminds me of something made in the 3D software Bryce which isn't widely available anymore. If budget allows then for something this specific you might want to hire someone with 3D modeling knowhow to make it for you. Could probably post a fairly specific Gig request on Craigslist or any number of freelance sites and get a fair rate on it.

> Seeking someone to do a 3D model of some topography for me. It'll include mountains and lowlands. I'll need it rendered in X number of views and I'll need it delivered at X by X pixel resolution in TIFF format. Here is an idea of the quality and style I'm after (image you posted here). Please email me two or three work samples and your rate.

Comment: There is a database fo high resolution survey data available [here](http://www2.jpl.nasa.gov/srtm/), which maps most of the globe (except not where I am). For fun watch [this](http://www2.jpl.nasa.gov/srtm/images/movies/Himalayas_Merged_Simfly_H264_cleared_1080.mov). Why use something that looks like a mountain when you can make one that is based on a real mountain.

Comment: Bryce was a lot of fun and I used to use it all of the time.  Although Bryce is not used any longer, a better alternative called [e-on vue](http://www.e-onsoftware.com/) is available.  They have several different options, including a free one.